# Есть ли во фразе речевая ошибка?

Tags: лексика

Словосочетание "письменно объяснить" содержит речевую ошибку? Насколько я понимаю, глагол "объяснить" характеризует устную речь

Answer (score 3):

Не только устную речь.

А как же "написать объяснительную"? Это документ.
В ответах здесь мы письменно объясняем правила, нюансы и т.п.